# String to ObjectId using JSON.parse

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am looking to create a dynamic where clause which includes a ObjectId. Not able to convert string into ObjectId with JSON parse.

Here is what I am trying to make work ...

```
var className = 'maths';
var studentId = '595d193cd4832d53bfc22cea'
var where = JSON.parse('{ "class.' + className + '.student":' + studentId + '}')

College.findOne(where);
```

My where clause should look below and above statement should run without error

```
{class.math.student: 595d193cd4832d53bfc22cea }
```

or

```
{class.math.student: ObjectId('595d193cd4832d53bfc22cea') }
```

Please help

Comment: You are using mongoose, so if the property in your schema is correctly defined with the `"type": Schema.Types.ObjectId` then mongoose will **do this for you**, which is part of the point in using the ODM in the first place. If this is not happening then your schema is "incorrect". Show your schema in your question so we can correct you. Also for the about the 1000th time **"JavaScript Objects are not JSON"**.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `where` object without parsing a string:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

var where = { class: {} };
where.class[className] = { student: new ObjectId(studentId) };
```

Comment: Sorry does not seem to work. Can object be passed as where clause ?

Comment: I believe it works, but there was a "new" missing (added in an edition now). Try now :)